# replace featured image from frontend

Tags: post-thumbnails, attachments

I'm using this code to add the alt text to my featured images on upload.

```
$image_title = get_post( $post->ID )->post_title;
// Sanitize the title:  remove hyphens, underscores & extra spaces:
$image_title = preg_replace( '%\s*[-_\s]+\s*%', ' ',  $image_title );
// Sanitize the title:  capitalize first letter of every word (other letters lower case):
$image_title = ucwords( strtolower( $image_title ) );
// Set the image Alt-Text
add_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $image_title );
```

It's working and I can see it on it's database table `wp_postmeta` under it's post ID.

Altough it's correctly registred on the database, the featured image doesn't have the Alt text (see the image bellow)

[image: missing Alt Text]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use [set_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_post_thumbnail/) to actually set featured image:

```
set_post_thumbnail($_POST['post_id'], $attachment_id);
```

Comment: Sorry, that piece of code is in my original one and now is also on my example. Even though, it doesn't woks...

Answer (score 0):

It's needed to pass the image ID from the `media_handle_upload` like this:

**First we get the new image ID**

```
$attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $_POST['post_id'] );
```

**Than we prepare the content of that `alt="text"`:**

```
// Prepare the alt="title"
$image_title = get_post( $post->ID )->post_title;
// Sanitize the title:  remove hyphens, underscores & extra spaces:
$image_title = preg_replace( '%\s*[-_\s]+\s*%', ' ',  $image_title );
// Sanitize the title:  capitalize first letter of every word (other letters lower case):
$image_title = ucwords( strtolower( $image_title ) );
```

**And finaly we set the new image `alt="text"`:**

```
add_post_meta( $attach_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', $image_title );
```

The reason the code above was failing, was because the `$post->ID` is the `ID` of the post itself and not the `attachment ID` (wich is the one we need).